# Return function in C

Tags: c, function, return

Is it possible to return a function in C? For example, in Python, we can do the following:

```py
def function1(n):
  def function2():
    print(n)
    print("Bar")
  return function2

function2 = function1("Foo")
function2()
```

What would the C equivalent be?

Comment: Closures are not supported in C.

Comment: You can return a function pointer, but that's about it. No closures. Use a more modern language if you want to do that.

Comment: @dbush Yes, I understand, I was simply using a closure to illustrate what I meant in a readable way.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Yes, thank you very much!